# SQL SELECT * FROM table WHERE colmn='value' без учёта пробелов

Tags: sql

Допустим есть таблица Text.

Данные:

```
[Id] [Val]
 1    Hello world
 2    Helloworld
 3    Hello      world
```

Нужно составить запрос типа 
SELECT * FROM Text 
WHERE Val='Helloworld'

И чтоб в результате были все эти три строки

Ну т.е. нужно чтобы запрос выбрал значения без учёта пробелов (их может быть много).

MSSQL

Comment: `REPLACE(Val, ' ', '') ='Helloworld'`

Comment: Да, это сработало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Text WHERE Val like 'Hello%world'
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EPQAEYZ.png
Не работает

Comment: @Tima исправил ошибку

Comment: Теперь, всё хорошо.
А можно сслыку где про эти символы можно узнать?

Comment: @Tima https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо.